# Object 'pos.words' not found error while doing Sentiment Analysis in R

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am preparing a text mining project by getting tweets from Twitter. I have done the first part and the second part of the project is sentiment analysis. I really don't know how to do sentiment analysis, so I have found some codes on the internet. They were using these codes with English positive and negative words but I have my own Turkish positive and negative words and I want to use them instead. tweet_clean is my clean tweet dataset, so I didn't make any changes to the code except that, but it doesn't work. I'm getting this error;

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'pos.words' not found
```

after running;

```
analysis <- score.sentiment(tweet_clean, pos.words, neg.words)
```

And the following codes after that don't work as well.

Please can you tell me what's wrong with these codes as if you are talking to a dumb person?

```
positive <- scan('C:/Users/samet/Desktop/twitter_steam_text_mining/pozitifkelimeler.txt', what = 'character', comment.char = ';', skipNul = TRUE)
negative <- scan('C:/Users/samet/Desktop/twitter_steam_text_mining/negatifkelimeler.txt', what = 'character', comment.char = ';', skipNul = TRUE)


score.sentiment <- function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
  
{
  require(plyr)
  require(stringr)
  
  scores <- laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words)
    
    {
    
    # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub() function:
    sentence <- gsub('https://','',sentence)
    sentence <- gsub('http://','',sentence)
    sentence <- gsub('[^[:graph:]]', ' ',sentence)
    sentence <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence <- gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
    sentence <- gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
    sentence <- str_replace_all(sentence,"[^[:graph:]]", " ")
    # and convert to lower case:
    sentence <- tolower(sentence)
    
    # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
    word.list <- str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
    # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
    words <- unlist(word.list)
    
    # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
    pos.matches <- match(words, pos.words)
    neg.matches <- match(words, neg.words)
    
    # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
    # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
    pos.matches <- !is.na(pos.matches)
    neg.matches <- !is.na(neg.matches)
    
    # TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
    score <- sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)
    
    return(score)
  }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )
  
  scores.df <- data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
  return(scores.df)
}

analysis <- score.sentiment(tweet_clean, pos.words, neg.words)
# sentiment score frequency table
table(analysis$score)


analysis %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=score)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "lightblue")+ 
  ylab("Frequency") + 
  xlab("sentiment score") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Sentiment scores of the tweets") +
  ggeasy::easy_center_title()


neutral <- length(which(analysis$score == 0))
positive <- length(which(analysis$score > 0))
negative <- length(which(analysis$score < 0))
Sentiment <- c("Positive","Neutral","Negative")
Count <- c(positive,neutral,negative)
output <- data.frame(Sentiment,Count)
output$Sentiment<-factor(output$Sentiment,levels=Sentiment)
ggplot(output, aes(x=Sentiment,y=Count))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Sentiment))+
  ggtitle("Barplot of Sentiment type of 4000 tweets")
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, not all of which seems to actually pertain to the question (e.g. the question isn't about ggplot, so we don't need any of the plotting-related code), but we can't run any of it without your data. Your error says that `pos.words` wasn't found—are you sure you've defined it?

Comment: @camille I just realized there was a code block that I did not take but I thought these were optional. Because I'm using Turkish positive words.                                                                                                  pos.words = c(positive,'upgrade','Congrats','prizes','prize','thanks','thnx',
              'Grt','gr8','plz','trending','recovering','brainstorm','leader')

Comment: If your code relies on an object being defined, unless it's part of a package you've loaded, it's not optional to actually define it—it needs to be somewhere in the scope of your code. If you add that definition in, do you still get an error?

Comment: No, I don't get an error anymore. It just looks unnecessary right now. I'll try changing those words into Turkish as well. Thanks for your help.